# jQuery: How can I use "$" instead of "jQuery"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple jQuery in my site, yet I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

The error only appears if I use "$" instead of "jQuery".

```
// This works
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#pass').keyup( ... );
});

// This doesn't
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pass').keyup( ... );
});
```

Do I need to do anything to use "$"?

Comment: I had found a simpler example which was easier to understand here https://wpza.net/using-dollar-sign-instead-of-jquery/

Answer (score 25):

You can wrap your code:

```
(function($) {
    // here $ would be point to jQuery object
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#pass').keyup( ... );
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: also, `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...` allows you to use the `$` inside of the ready function.

Comment: With this wrapper functions are out of global vision. How can I use $ in the functions?

Answer (score 12):

You probably have jQuery noConflict mode enabled somewhere in your code, see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
jQuery.noConflict(); // Stops $ from workng
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks a lot, Dan (Y)

Answer (score 2):

First, jQuery objects are a lot like arrays, so `[object DOMWindow]` actually *is* a jQuery object most likely.

You might have a syntax error, like a missing semicolon, right before the call to `$(document)` which is making the `$` look like a property access.