# Custom jQuery not working on Wordpress Ninja Forms plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, ninja-forms

I am having some problems when I want to add custom jQuery code that affects the form.

For example when someone clicks an input or radio button another input or element to be hidden or shown.I tried to get a result like `console.log('trigger');` when clicked or something else but nothing in dev. console appeared.Also, I tried the following methods:

To call the `click` event with `.on('click', function()...` or to call the event with `.trigger('click');`, or to change the event to `change`

To embed the script within a file from ninja forms or to put it inside the page at the ending of `body` tag in `footer.php`

To change the opening declaration of jQuery to work inside a function like this : `(function($) {$(document).ready(function(){.....`

I know that I could try another plugin, I tried one and the custom jQuery works but I really like this one and don't know why this is happening ...

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working?

Comment: Yes, I did manage to work it out in some way or another at that time, thanks for the reply!  I also saw that the answer helped more people, keep on the good work!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Not sure if you need help with this any more as it's been some time since you posted your question, but this may help others in the future. I had the same/similar issue with not being able to run JS/jQuery on the Ninja Forms and found that it's because Ninja Forms load their forms asynchronously. So, when your document.ready function runs, the form doesn't yet exist and it's not able to bind.

Ninja Forms have their own event ready state that can be used as follows:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'nfFormReady', function( e, layoutView ) {
    // Your code goes here...
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I spent way too long trying to find that... Is that in NF docs somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if it's in the documentation as their site appears to be down at the moment. However, I think I actually found reference to it on the GitHub page: https://github.com/wpninjas/ninja-forms/issues/2436 and then searched Google for an example of the `nfformReady` in use.

Comment: @JoelWorsham - The NinjaForms site appears to be up and running again now. However, I searched and searched their docs and codex but there doesn't appear to be any reference there to the nfFormReady event... So I must have just gotten it from the example on the Github page above.

Comment: What's the best solution to add to this to allow the use of $ within the IF statement?

Comment: @Lee - What IF statement are you referring to? Can't you just use `jQuery` instead of `$`? - If you really need to use `$`, then check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635600/jquery-how-can-i-use-instead-of-jquery

Comment: Awesome! Since this question is related to wordpress, people might also be interested that you might need to also create a no conflict variable to use for your jquery code because the "$" is protected. I had both the problem listed on this posting and what I describe. After fixing both, I have custom jQuery working with NinjaForms.

Comment: If anyone else out there has things set up where "nfFormReady" _should be_ firing and _still_ isn't just make sure that your js code comes before NF's (which they insert at the bottom of the page). Also, for anyone wanting/needing to know where "nfFormReady" is fired in NF code it's in /wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/assets/js/min/front-end.js.

Answer (score 1):

The event isn't registered simply because the elements you're trying to bind the event to do not exist yet at that moment (on document load). Ninja forms loads the form contents asynchronously, so you'll have to wait until the form is fully loaded and then add your event listeners. 
This works for me:

```
var formExists = setInterval(function() {
  if ($(".nf-form-cont").length) {
    // Set your event listeners here, example:
    $("#nf-field-1").click(function(e) {
      console.log("click!");
    }
    clearInterval(formExists);
  }
}, 100); // check every 100ms
```

Comment: I don't know why this was voted down. Granted, it's not an officially supported "ready" event, but with other libraries I've worked with that don't offer an event for "ready" or "loaded" I've done this type of approach. It's still a valid answer even if the better answer is to use the one built into NF.