# Autofill form with existing form values

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, ninja-forms

I am trying to get a form field to autofill with the same value as another field using Ninja Forms and Wordpress. I have looked at some solutions using JQuery but none of them seem to work. Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is a link to the form: https://optionsqa.wpengine.com/test-page/

I want to get the content in "COPY THIS LINK" to automatically populate the field below.

This is the script I am trying:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('.copy-link').on('change', function() {
   jQuery('.favorite-link-field').val($(this).val());
 }); 
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution (updated to include ninja form ready state, as per comments):

I prefer using the `id` over `class` since classes can be used multiple times. That being said:

This will update when `#nf-field-10` or `Favorites Link` is changed.

```
jQuery(document).on( 'nfFormReady', function( e, layoutView ) {
 jQuery('#nf-field-10').on('change', function() {
   jQuery('#nf-field-10').val(jQuery('#nf-field-16').val());
 }); 
});
```

Comment: Not working! :( Could ninja forms be preventing this from working?

Comment: not sure. Tested this in DevTools and it worked as described. Based on both answers not working, it might be ninja forms.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! After what you said I dug further and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875677/custom-jquery-not-working-on-wordpress-ninja-forms-plugin.  It seems to work as it now listens to a regular print function, but how do I apply this to the code you provided?

Comment: Please remember to mark as the answer / upvote if this works for you.